How do I make a golden helmet in minecraft that, when worn, makes the player 2 times bigger?
I'm looking to make a golden helmet that when worn will make the player size twice as big. I have seen other commands, however none worked and I do not have enough knowledge to do it myself.

Welcome to Arqade! Please see our guide on asking Minecraft commands questions, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far.” Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

Which commands have you tried, what was the result and what about them didn't work for you?
